# How do I convert the output of a function to a usable variable?

Tags: lua, lua-table

in Lua, I have a large number of tables named A-Z (I referenced just 2 below). I have a function `NextVar(PreviousVar)` which I use to cycle the output from A-Z. but when I try to print a value from a table (`A[1]` for example), it prints `nil` instead. How can I transform the return value from the function into a usable variable?

````
A = {10, 33, 35}
B = {15, 55, 45}

local alphabet = "1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

function NextVar(PreviousVar)
    local index = string.find(alphabet, PreviousVar)
    if index then
        index = (index % #alphabet) + 1 -- move to next letter, wrapping at end
        return alphabet:sub(index, index)    
    end
end

PreviousVar = "1"

repeat
    if NextVar(PreviousVar) != nil then
        x = NextVar(PreviousVar)
        print(x)  -- works as it prints A,B,C,D, etc
        print(x[1])  -- just prints nil
        PreviousVar = NextVar(PreviousVar)
    end
until PreviousVar == nil```
````

Answer (score 2):

`NextVar` returns strings. "A", "B", ...

Why do you expect `x[1]` to be a value of table `A`? There is no relation between the string `"A"` and the table `A`.

If you want to refer to those tables using the return values of `NextVar` you can use the global environment table `_G`. `_G[x][1]` will return the first element of `A` for `x` being `"A"`

Usually you would just have a table of tables rather than accessing global tables through their names.

```
local myTables = {
  {10, 33, 35},
  {15, 55, 45},
}

for i,v in ipairs(myTables) do
  print(i)
  print(v[1])
end
```